# LaravelTrust and LaravelAuthUI can't import role to database

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-8, roles, laratrust

I have a problem with LaraTrust `$User->attachRole('user')`, and Laravel Auth UI. I want to attach a role upon registering a new User. After the registering, I don't see any data in the roles table.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
         'name' => $data['name'],
         'email' => $data['email'],
         'phonenumber' => $data['phonenumber'],
         'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]); 
    $User->attachRole('user');
}
```

Comment: I fount solutions: just remove $user and write like this ])->attachRole('user');

Answer (score 0):

You are directly returning the created user before attaching the role.

Either:

```php
$user = User::create([]);
$user->attachRole('user');
return $user;
```

Or

```php
return User::create([])->attachRole('user');
```